# Opening vim with splits, vertical resize not working properly

Tags: vim, neovim

Im trying to get nvim to open with a vertical split and then two terminals on the right side.

```
+--------------+
¦        ¦     ¦
¦  file  ¦  t1 ¦
¦        ¦-----¦
¦        ¦  t2 ¦
¦        ¦     ¦
+--------------+
```

However, the autocmd that does **:vertical resize** only works to enlarge the window, not shrink it. So +20 works, but not -20. Anyone know what the problem might be?

```
au VimEnter * vsplit
au VimEnter * :wincmd l
au VimEnter * :vertical resize +20
```

Comment: why do you use `vertical` here? just use `:resize -20`

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo I tried both, made no difference.

Comment: Well then it seems like something else does interfere with your vim. Start vim without any settings: `vim -u NONE` open a split with `:split` and then use `:resize -20` it does work doesn't it?

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo Yes, it works when I run it without any settings. How would I go about finding the cause?

Comment: hmm I am not aware of a way to directly find it out. I think you will have to binary search your plugins. Deactivate half of them until you find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can't add a comment,

My answer does not match your question but may be helpful

Maybe you can try the plugin:

[GoldenView](https://github.com/zhaocai/GoldenView.Vim)

This will resize your active window automatically